# YamlSlurper cannot parse Enum value

Tags: java, groovy, yaml

I have yaml:

```
- flowId: "2021:6:10:20:22:7"
  flowType: "BIG"
  summary: "Description"
  flowStatus: "NEW"
  createdDate: "2021-06-10"
  lastModifiedDate: "2021-06-10"

class Flow{
...
FlowType flowType;
...
}

Enum FlowType{
SMALL,MEDIUM, BIG;
}
```

Parsing file using YamlSlurper:

```
def flowList = new YamlSlurper().parseText(new File(myFile).text).collect { it as Flow }
```

error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to model.FlowType`

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YAML slurper is a cute tool to quickly read a YAML file or string
and deal with it to the degree, that you would use the other slurpers:
get some basic data types inside lists and maps and just use that.

Your attempt to cast the map to the object only works for very basic
objects.  The cast basically gets unrolled to something like:

```
[a: 42] as X
```

becomes

```
def x = new X()
map.each{ k, v ->
    x."$k" = v
}
```

This does:

- not coerce/convert types
- fails if keys in the map, that are not set-able properties in the
  resulting object

If you need proper object mapping, the slurpers are not directly useful
most of the time.  You would rather switch to using something made for
that task -- e.g. like Jackson.

Lucky for us, the YAML slurper just uses Jackson (it actually just
transforms the YAML into JSON and then uses the JSON slurper to give you
your data back).

Following an example of how to load the YAML data into objects using
Jackson (all deps are already there, if you already see `YamlSlurper`):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLMapper

def yamlStr = """\
- flowId: "2021:6:10:20:22:7"
  flowType: "BIG"
  summary: "Description"
  flowStatus: "NEW"
  createdDate: "2021-06-10"
  lastModifiedDate: "2021-06-10"
"""

enum FlowType{ SMALL,MEDIUM, BIG }

@groovy.transform.ToString
class Flow {
    FlowType flowType
}

def flows = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory()).with{
    configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    readValue(yamlStr, new TypeReference<List<Flow>>(){})
}

println flows
// → Flow(BIG)
```

Comment: ok I understand. Would this work with SnakeYaml out of the box?

Comment: @Sree I don't understand your question. How much more "out of the box" do you want to get? It will work more or less the same with SnameYAML, but you would at least have to `@Grab` it.